# Чтение текстового файла в C#

Tags: c#, файлы, текст

Решил поучаствовать в олимпиаде по информатике и тут наткнулся на проблему, поскольку плохо представляю чтение чисел в C# из текстового файла. Как можно считать из текстового файла двумерный массив целых/вещественных чисел?
Формат файла примерно такой:
    2 3 //размерность матрицы
    1.2 4.9 -3.2
    1.1. 2.2. 3.3

Comment: Определяется тем, как он в этом текстовом файле представлен.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень просто.

Для начала, как превратить строку из файла в список чисел? Очень просто: вам нужен StreamReader

```
var infile = new StreamReader("your file name here");
var line = infile.ReadLine();
if (line == null)
    throw new SomeAppropriateException("expect line in input file");
```

Отлично, что дальше? Дальше считанную строку надо разбить на числа. Например, так:

```
var ints = line.Split().Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToList();
```

(понятно, что это и почему работает?)

Имея первые два числа, у вас есть размерности массива. Теперь можно завести сам массив, и точно так же считать в него данные. (Возможно, кое-где понадобится `Convert.ToDouble`.)